# What's a good, cross-platform way to concatenate paths in C?

Tags: c, path, cross-platform, concatenation

At the moment, I have a `path_concat(char* path_fragment_a, char* path_fragment_b)` function, which simply concatenates together `path_fragment_a`, `PATH_DIVIDER`, and `path_fragment_b`. (PATH_DIVIDER is #defined in an #ifdef block, so it's `\` on Windows and `/` everywhere else.)

But I can't help thinking this seems:

- a bit of a kludge.
- something which must surely be covered by a fairly common library, which would be better to use if available, so I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Googling it just turned up a lot of results about Python's `os.path.join` (which would be ideal, *except it's Python, not C*), so I was wondering if anyone was aware of a cleaner/more standard solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should use `snprintf`, not concatenation operations, to construct a string all at once. This is the safe and efficient way. Concatenation may be idiomatic in script languages but it's inefficient and harmful (prone to dangerous errors) in C.

With that said, ever since the first version of DOS that had directories (2 or 3; I forget which it was), `'/'` has been valid as a path separator on DOS, and it has always been valid on Windows as well. The only reason it was not used is that many legacy command line programs designed before DOS supported directories interpret `'/'` as a "switch" (option) character in their command line parsing. The only real-world system in the past 20 years not to support `'/'` as a path separator is pre-OSX MacOS, and I don't think that's a viable target anymore, so in my opinion, you should simply always use `'/'`, and avoid polluting your code with gratuitous "portability".

Comment: Although recent Windows version accept '/', I'm pretty sure I remember old versions of DOS rejecting it (at least in the command interpreter).  Maybe I'm mis-remembering...

Comment: As I said, some DOS command line programs interpreted `'/'` as a switch character themselves before passing the string to the filesystem access calls, in which case you're out of luck. But at the filesystem level it always worked.

Comment: Ah, good point on `snprintf` (and yes, I am more accustomed to scripting languages). So I guess the best options are either basically the same as I have now (but with `snprintf` instead of `strcat`), or to assume (probably accurately) that it won't ever run on a system where `/` doesn't do the right thing. Thanks!

Comment: If you really want to support different separators, you can let the format string be defined per-target-platform (for instance `"%s/%s/%s"` versus `"%s\\%s\\%s"`) or use `%c`'s in the format string to allow insertion of an arbitrary separator character.

Comment: Python's `os.path.join` has a feature whereby if subsequent paths begin with `/`, then all previous path part is discarded. This is useful if you want to append a file name to `CWD` if it doesn't begin with `/`, but use it as-is if it begins with `/`. Just using `snprintf` doesn't give you this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such function in the Standard C library to join file paths. You'll have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently GLib has some functions (like `g_build_path`) and macros (`G_DIR_SEPARATOR_S` and others) for this.